# Three.js issue with object position when using matrix make rotation

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to rotate an object I called "moon" (its a sphere) trying to use matrix for that instead moon.rotation.y in this way:

```
moon.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(Math.PI/100));
```

The good thing is that the object is rotating well, but I dont know why the object changed his initial position:

```
moon.position.set(30,1,30);
```

to (0,0,0)

Could you tell me why, if I execute the first line, the object is placed in 0,0,0 and if not remains in the right position (30,1,30)?

Thanks.

Regards.

Jose.

Comment: 1. "I'm ... trying to use matrix for that instead [of] moon.rotation.y". Why? 2. Without your complete code it is impossible to answer. 3. Use the debugger and step through the non-minified three.js code and you can probably see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

applyMatrix() modifies the matrix directly. When you set the position the matrix is only updated in the render loop or if you call updateMatrix(). So depending on  your order of operations, calling applyMatrix() could definitely clobber your position setting.

The three.js documentation page on Matrix transformations is helpful: https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Matrix-transformations.

Also, I wrote a series of test cases for myself to understand the various ways to apply rotations and transformations of meshes and geometries. Might be helpful:  http://rwoodley.org/?p=1073

Comment: Thanks a lot Bob, the answer + your blog was really helpful! Kind Regards. Jose.